# Magento 1.9.2.4 to magento 2.4.5 data migration tool issue

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am usign the data migration tool to migrate data from Magento 1.9.2.4 to Magento 2.4.5.
When I run the command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml
```

it does not show any progress or even an error.

Comment: Have you configured config.xml ? added source/destination db credentials ?

Comment: Yes I have configured it.

Comment: @Pawan can you help?